# Sql find only one hashtag not two

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

How to find in a MySQL database?:

```
# Some title
```

(In a text field most of the titles are:
`## Some title`.
But there are some mistakes with only one #. How can I find them in a big database?. I know that they are only in the field text_post)

I could find that it could be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM blog
WHERE text_post LIKE '%#%'
```

But, how can I find when there is only one # and not two?

If I understand, it is not possible to use regex here. Is that right?

Comment: What does ? here mean?. Is it like regex? In regex would be 0 or 1 space

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of regex :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an extract clause to eliminate the double `##`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog
WHERE (text_post LIKE '%#%' AND text_post NOT LIKE '%##%')
```

Comment: Probably could be written as `text_post LIKE '#%' AND text_post NOT LIKE '##%'` (removing % prefixes)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Possibly, im not sure if they are only at the beginning though.

Comment: It is only at the beginning of the line. Anyway it is a good observation.

Answer (score 3):

```
^    - Beginning of line
#    - hashtag
[^#] - Any character other than hashtag
|    - OR operator
$    - End of line
```

---

```
select  *
from    blog
where   text_post rlike '^#([^#]|$)'
```

Comment: The big question now is which method would have better performance +1

Comment: rlike are you sure about that? shouln't it be like?

Comment: I copy-paste your code and it gives me an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rlike '^#([^#]|$)'' at line 2 Do I need anything to activate regex in MySql?

Comment: This is a copy-pasted working code. `SELECT VERSION(); -- 5.7.11-log`

Comment: I amb working in local. I use Mamp and I have the last version of Mamp with MySql 5.6.28